# Scheduling tasks with GoDaddy shared hosting using Plesk

Tags: php, godaddy, shared-hosting, plesk

How do I schedule a task in GoDaddy using Plesk? How do I set the Path to an executable file in the schedule task?

I have the path as `G:\PleskVhosts\[domain.tld]\[path]\[file_name]` but I'm getting an error as:

> Failed with error: 'G:\PleskVhosts\httpdocs\myfolder\cron.php' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

The version for PHP that I'm using is 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you put it in httpdocs inside the domain:

`G:\PleskVhosts\anything.com\httpdocs\demo\anayhting.php`